# how do I push a branch in git to a remote

Tags: git

I am trying to do a Rails 3 upgrade.

So what I did is a created a branch -b rails-3

I've been working in that branch

I want to push it into a remote repository (just in case something goes down on my local machine)

How do I do that?

If I do git push  it says everything is up to date....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/branch-name` should do the trick. It will create a branch called `branch-name` on the `origin` repository and copy your `HEAD` to it.

Comment: What's the difference between doing this and just `git push origin new-branch-name`?

Comment: @Jin: Nothing. I personally just find it less error-prone to explicitly write the refspec.

Comment: do I substitute the name of my remote repository for 'origin' or do I explicitly use the word origin?

Comment: Use whatever the remote is named. If you didn't explicitly set the remote name when you cloned it then it defaults to `origin`. You can run `git remote` to see the names of the remotes you have, and `git remote -v` to show more details about them.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: you might be one of the very few people in the world to find it *less* error-prone to type the full ref name ;)  Of course, they're only equivalent if the user's `HEAD` is pointing to `branch-name`, and you're using a recent version of git, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7455445/223092